# getting blank page in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

[image]

I am trying to learn about web services and wcf but it doesn't go well. I get same problem with wcf so I tried webservice but get same page with this too. Even when I make exactly same things with wcf or web service example videos, I get this screen. What am I doing wrong and why is it happening ? And ofcourse how can I fix it ?

My .asmx class:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string GetMessage(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

My .aspx page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table style="font-family:Arial">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and my codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HelloService.HelloWebServiceSoapClient client = 
            new HelloService.HelloWebServiceSoapClient();

        Label1.Text = client.GetMessage(TextBox1.Text);

    }
```

Comment: Pick *one* technology and learn it - instead of jumping between ASMX (legacy and deprecated) and WCF, just focus on WCF.   As for the issue you're seeing, how are you getting there?  Are you running it from VS?  Did you set the start page in the project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing something here.

What page are you expecting to see ?  Your .aspx page ? Or your .asmx file ?  If so, you just need to right-click on that file in Visual Studio and select "Set as start page".

But normally, with WCF services, you should have a **.svc** file in there, and this should be your starting point  (but WCF services aren't meant to have a "starting webpage").

Here's a link to my step-by-step tutorial for creating WCF web services from scratch.

[Creating WCF web services](http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm)

This'll show you how to create JSON web services, which you can then call like this:

[image]